# Passing a json value to another react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native, graphql

I have a parent functional component named Dashboard and a child class component named DashboardTable. I'm making a graphql call in the parent class and want to pass the result into the child like this `<DashboardTable data={opportunityData}/>.`

problem: I can get see the data in the parent but its not showing in the child

Here is my code. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong

**Dashboard**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "bootstrap/js/src/collapse.js";
import DashboardTable from "../DashboardTable";
import { API } from "@aws-amplify/api";
import config from "../../aws-exports";
import * as queries from "../../graphql/queries";

export default function Dashboard() {
  API.configure(config);
  async function asyncCall() {
    const gqlreturn = await API.graphql({
      query: queries.listMockOppsTables,
    });
    //console.log(gqlreturn.data.listMockOppsTables); // result: { "data": { "listTodos": { "items": [/* ..... */] } } }
    return gqlreturn;
  }

  const [opportunityTable, changeOpportunityTable] = useState(asyncCall());
  console.log(opportunityTable); // this works! returns a promise

  return (
    <div>
      <section className="py-5 mt-5">
        <div className="container py-5">
          <h2 className="fw-bold text-center">
            Your upcoming shadowing events
            <br />
            <br />
          </h2>

          <DashboardTable data={opportunityTable}></DashboardTable>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**DashboardTable**

```
import React from "react";
import "bootstrap/js/src/collapse.js";
import Navigation from "../Navigation";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { API } from "@aws-amplify/api";
import config from "../../aws-exports";
import * as queries from "../../graphql/queries";

export class DashboardTable extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      opportunityData: this.props,
    };
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.opportunityData); // this doesnt work :( no data
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          className="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 mx-auto"
          style={{ maxWidth: 900 }}
        >
          {this.opportunityData.map((opportunity) => (
            <div className="col mb-4">
              <div>
                <a href="#">
                  <img
                    className="rounded img-fluid shadow w-100 fit-cover"
                    src="assets/img/products/awsLogo.jpg"
                    style={{
                      height: 250,
                    }}
                  />
                </a>
                <div className="py-4">
                  <span
                    className="badge mb-2"
                    style={{ margin: 2, backgroundColor: "#ff9900" }}
                  >
                    {opportunity.interview_type}
                  </span>
                  <span
                    className="badge bg mb-2"
                    style={{ margin: 2, backgroundColor: "#ff9900" }}
                  >
                    {opportunity.level}
                  </span>
                  <span
                    className="badge bg mb-2"
                    style={{ margin: 2, backgroundColor: "#ff9900" }}
                  >
                    {opportunity.ShadowReverse}
                  </span>
                 
                  
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default DashboardTable;
```

Comment: You should use `this.props.data`. Or I see you assigned the props to the state, you may also use `this.state.opportunityData.data`.

Comment: @PeterTam Thanks for your reply. I'm still getting nothing in the props after this change. Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Comment: Try changing constructor statement in child component like this: `constructor(props){  
    super(props);  ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few pointers

Call api on mount in parent's useEffect

In child directly use the passed property in child

```
function Dashboard() {
  API.configure(config);
  async function asyncCall() {
    const gqlreturn = await API.graphql({
      query: queries.listMockOppsTables,
    });
    //console.log(gqlreturn.data.listMockOppsTables); // result: { "data": { "listTodos": { "items": [/* ..... */] } } }
    return gqlreturn;
  }
  // initialize with empty array
  const [opportunityTable, changeOpportunityTable] = useState([]);
  console.log(opportunityTable); // this works! returns a promise

  // call api to fetch data on mount
  useEffect(( => {  

     const fetchData = async () => {

       const response = await asyncCall();
       changeOpportunityTable(response)
     }

     fetchData()


  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <section className="py-5 mt-5">
        <div className="container py-5">
          <h2 className="fw-bold text-center">
            Your upcoming shadowing events
            <br />
            <br />
          </h2>

          <DashboardTable data={opportunityTable}></DashboardTable>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
}


class DashboardTable extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    //this.state = {
    //  opportunityData: this.props,
    //};
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.data); // this doesnt work :( no data
    return (
      <div>
        <div
          className="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 mx-auto"
          style={{ maxWidth: 900 }}
        >


//map thru data prop            {this.props.data?.map((opportunity) => (
                <div className="col mb-4">
                  <div>
                    <a href="#">
                      <img
                        className="rounded img-fluid shadow w-100 fit-cover"
                        src="assets/img/products/awsLogo.jpg"
                        style={{
                          height: 250,
                        }}
                      />
                    </a>
                    <div className="py-4">
                      <span
                        className="badge mb-2"
                        style={{ margin: 2, backgroundColor: "#ff9900" }}
                      >
                        {opportunity.interview_type}
                      </span>
                      <span
                        className="badge bg mb-2"
                        style={{ margin: 2, backgroundColor: "#ff9900" }}
                      >
                        {opportunity.level}
                      </span>
                      <span
                        className="badge bg mb-2"
                        style={{ margin: 2, backgroundColor: "#ff9900" }}
                      >
                        {opportunity.ShadowReverse}
                      </span>
                     
                      
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              ))}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

There are some bugs in the child like this.state.opportunityData = this.props, that end part should likely be this.props.opportunityData, however to get you going with the async call in the parent component give this a try

```
const [opportunityTable, changeOpportunityTable] = useState([]);

async function asyncCall() {
  const gqlreturn = await API.graphql({
    query: queries.listMockOppsTables,
  });
    
  changeOpportunityTable(gqlreturn);
}

useEffect(() => asyncCall(), []);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I console.log(gqlreturn) inside your version of  the function above I get nothing returned. Not even undefined.

Comment: Ideally convert Dashboard table to functional component or directly do this.props?.map(